# Leveraging maps.googleapis browser caching, as per Google PageSpeed Insights advice

Tags: javascript, google-api, http-caching

The following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my-key>&libraries=places"></script>
```

Results in a warning when the page is scanned from Google PageSpeed Insights:

> Consider Fixing:
>
> Leverage browser caching Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs
>   the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk
>   rather than over the network. Leverage browser caching for the
>   following cacheable resources:
>
> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/…&libraries=places
> ```
>
> (30 minutes)

How can I leverage the browser caching from 30 minutes to something higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch it as php with CURL from your server